# Why am I getting issues when importing dns.resolver?

Tags: python

I'm having issues when trying to import dns.resolver from dnspython.
Whenever I import dns.resolver, I get an error (shown below). I've force reinstalled the module, restarted the computer, and I continue to get the same error. Thanks in advance.

> ```
> import dns.resolver
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
>   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'dns'
> ```

The version of python I'm using is 3.6.6

Comment: Are you installing it via pip? Or are you installing via github and running setup.py?

Comment: I'm using it via pip.

Answer (score -1):

There's an issue with installing via `pip`, but if you do you'll want to do this to import resolver (same goes for other classes):

```
from dns import resolver
```

Also, the examples you find online may change slightly.

This:

```
import dns.name
n = dns.name.from_text('www.dnspython.org')
o = dns.name.from_text('dnspython.org')
```

Becomes this:

```
from dns import name
n = name.from_text('www.dnspython.org')
o = name.from_text('dnspython.org')
```